# Contact form won't show content

Tags: php, forms, contacts

This is actually my first post here. Might be a semicolon problem but I'll give it a try because my headeache is bigger than the Eiffel tower.

So I've added a contact form on my website but there's a problem with it, since it is sending the email but when I receive it is empty. It only shows the text from the PHP file (Name:, Email:, etc), but no contect from the input form.

Code looks like this:
**HTML**

```
    <div class="contact-form bottom">
                    <h2>Send a message</h2>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

And **PHP**:

```
       <?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$status = array(

'type'=>'success',

'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '

);


    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 

    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));  

    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 


    $email_from = $email;

    $email_to = 'a.truta@icloud.com';//replace with your email


    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;


    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');


    echo json_encode($status);

    die;
```

Please help, I'm going crazy in here!

Comment: you're simply assuming success. you never bother actually checking the `mail()` return value, so even if that blew up and barfed all over the floor, you still send out "Success". and have you done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what PHP's receiving?

Comment: Don't use `@` when you're debugging a script. You want to see all the warnings, since they may indicate the problems.

Comment: I know what you are talking about and I don't want to sound stupid, but I'm new in this field and my first priority is front-end. That's why I'm having trouble with a simple contact form..

Answer (score 1):

As Marc said, you should be doing some validation on the form. Here's something I've quickly knocked up for you. It's not perfect and I haven't had chance to test it, but it'll give you a better starting point for your form processing. Not sure what the relevance of `json_encode` is doing in your code.

```
<?php

$toemail = "you@email.address";

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $errors = [];

    // Validate name
    if ((isset($_POST['name'])) and (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['name']))) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Name is invalid";
    }

    // Validate email
    if ((isset($_POST['email'])) and (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $errors[] = "The email is invalid";
    }

    // Validate message
    if ((isset($_POST['message'])) and (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z _-]+$/", $_POST['message']))) {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    } else {
        $errors[] = "The message is invalid";
    }

    if ((isset($name)) and (isset($email)) and (isset($message)) {
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
        if(@mail($toemail, 'New contact form email', $message, $headers)) {
            echo "<p>Mail Sent Successfully</p>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Mail Not Sent Successfully</p>\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Form validation has failed</p>";
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "<p>" . $error . "</p>\n";
        }
    }
} 

?>
```

Comment: Ok, this is the validation, but where should I put it exactly? Should I add it to the existing php "sendemail" file I have?

Comment: Don't add it to the existing PHP, just replace it. Also, technically speaking you don't need to have a separate HTML and PHP file, you can embed the HTML form into the "else" of the main "if", although I personally don't like doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the problem lies in the JS file. Without this code, the email arrives exactly how it has been sent, with content & all.

JS File:

```
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```